# Passing ASP.NET Elements to JavaScript Functions

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have created the following text-box and label:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server"/>
<asp:Label   ID="MyLabel"   runat="server"/>
```

Moreover, I have created the following JavaScript function:

```
function characterLimit(myTextBox, myLabel)
{
    myLabel.innerHTML = myTextBox.value.length + '/' + myTextBox.maxLength;
}
```

Finally, in the code-behind, I have performed the following:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("OnKeyUp", "characterLimit(MyTextBox, MyLabel);");
```

`characterLimit()` gets called. However, nothing happens; it is as though I am passing `MyTextBox` and `MyLabel` incorrectly (above). What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ClientID` property. This will help in the case you start using `MasterPages`, which changes the controls `IDs`.

But, in this specific case, I guess it's just about sticking quotes around the `IDs` when sending as parameters.

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("OnKeyUp", "characterLimit('" + MyTextBox.ClientID + "','" +  MyLabel.ClientID + "');");
```

Following a suggestion in the comments, you should also slightly change your `Javascript` code:

```
function characterLimit(myTextBox, myLabel)
{
    document.getElementById(myLabel).innerHTML = myTextBox.value.length + '/' + document.getElementById(myTextBox).maxLength;
}
```

And, just as a tip, have you tried `jQuery` yet?

Comment: Those IDs need to be wrapped in document.getElementById() to work with the characterLimit() method as presented. `TextBox1.Attributes.Add("OnKeyUp", "characterLimit(document.getElementById('" + MyTextBox.ClientID + "'),document.getElementById('" +  MyLabel.ClientID + "'));");`

Comment: The OP can do this in the `Javascript` function to keep the code clean.

Comment: Agreed that would be the better place for it.

Comment: I ended up using jQuery. Thank you for the suggestion. :-)

Comment: Com certeza vai diminuir seu trabalho codificando Javascript. :P